# can't update a page template

Tags: magento2, template

Hi all and nice to meet you.

Some days ago I've modified vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml in order to add a static phrase to every product page.
I know it's not the right way and i should rather override in app/design/ but it worked and it was only for few days.
I regenerated di, static and cache:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Everything worked and the phrase was online.

Now I've removed the phrase from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml. I do the regeneration of everything (di, static and cache) and the phrase is still there. I search for the phrase in the filesystem and it's only inside var/page_cache files. 
Why regenerating the cache put the phrase in if it's not present in my templates?
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Jus delete var/page_cache and regenerate static.

Comment: Nope.  
The phrase is still present.  
  
If I search it with `grep -rl "phrase" .` it shows only results in ./var/page_cache/
Even after deleting ./var/page_cache/ and regenerating static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Cosimo welcome to the community,

I'm not sure in which mode your store is. Production mode automatically does the compile. Since you have manually instructed the command `setup:static-content:deploy`

This creates pub/static, generated/code and other folder you can see here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Now that you have made changes to an html file and issued compilation, the files are now loaded from pub/static folder.

So your solution would be to:

```
rm -rf pub/static, var/view_preprocessed, var/cache, var/page_cache, generated/code
```

Running compile again those folders will be re-populated from current source data (which doens't contain you core modification static phrase)

If my answer resolves your issue, please mark this as solved.

Comment: Thank you very much. Hope to be usefull to the community growth. 
Unfortunately the generated content still show the phrase (and also some 404 on js like https://*****/static/version1590171754/frontend/Venustheme/CustomTheme/it_IT/Ves_Productlist/js/productlist.js ).
The store is in production mode

Comment: Maybe i need also to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` before compile and static content ?
I'm in production and don't want to break everything :D

Comment: Yes of course, run the -rm -rf command to remove those files. Then setup:upgrade then compile.

Comment: Also visit the website in Incognito mode, since it won't load the js files from browser cache

Comment: Since you're in Production mode. You should also clear generated/code folder. Updated solution above

Comment: The phrase is still there.. :(        
      
And the javascripts are really missing: I've noticed that the static content generation generates only .min.js, but the pages are trying to load the .js not minified that are no more present..
    
what a mess!

Comment: Did you revert back your changes from /vendor folder? I spent hours on a similar issue a while back and the only way to fix it was to have the vendor templates core files regenerated

Comment: Great! @maurisource web reverting back vendor folder worked! Thank you very much.
Do you know why and what's happened?